# Power reserve mode - lightning bolt

Tags: power, apple-watch

I cant get the watch out of power mode.  It has a lightning bolt on the screen.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

## Apple Watch - Power Reserve

**Power Reserve allows you to continue to see the time on your Apple Watch while preserving your battery life.**

[image: Watch face showing the time in power reserve] 
Your Apple Watch will automatically enter Power Reserve if the battery gets too low, and you might see [image: Charge icon] next to the time. In Power Reserve, press the side button to show the current time in a 24-hour format. The time will display for six seconds.

While your Apple Watch is in Power Reserve, your Apple Watch and iPhone won't communicate, and you can't access other watch features.

**Turn off Power Reserve**
To turn your device back on, press and hold the side button until you see the Apple logo and wait for your Apple Watch to restart. You might need to charge your Apple Watch first.

**Turn on Power Reserve**
If you need to, you can turn on Power Reserve. Press and hold the side button until you see the Power Off, Power Reserve, and Lock Device options. Then drag the slider to turn on Power Reserve.

You can also turn on Power Reserve using Glances. Swipe up on the watch face to open Glances, then swipe left or right to find the Battery Glance. Tap Power Reserve, then tap Proceed.

Source: [Apple KB - Using Power Reserve](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204525)

Comment: What if that doesn’t work? I hold down the digital crown and I still have the lightning bolt

Comment: Very likely it needs charging. If it doesn't charge, get the charger &/or battery checked out.

Answer (score 2):

This means that your Apple Watch has battery below 2%. You must put your Apple Watch on charge and hold down the Digital Crown and side button. This will put your Apple Watch onto its normal mode.